# (cannot find) python countable attribute most_common()

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nltk

novice here. I'm walking myself through the nltk book and another Python intro book.
I came across most_common() earlier on in the nltk book, and though I couldn't have it working nor find a solution at the time, I created a little function that did the trick in that particular exercise and kept going. 
Now I need it again, but I don't think I'll be able to get around it as easily (the exercise is about the most common word lengths in a particular text), plus I know I will find it again in later examples, and I'd like to be able to follow, since, as I said, I'm a novice.

In theory, I should be able to do this:

```
fdist = FreqDist(len(w) for w in text1)

fdist.most_common()
[(3, 50223), (1, 47933), (4, 42345), (2, 38513) ...
```

However, Python tells me this:

```
AttributeError: 'FreqDist' object has no attribute 'most_common'
```

I found that most_common() is an attribute of counter objects (http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) and (http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections#collections.Counter). I get the idea that perhaps I should be importing something (a module?), but what I have tried importing either doesn't work (not defined or non-existent messages) or does not contain it -I tried

```
import collections
```

no error there, but most_common() is not listed when I enter dir(collections) or dir(*builtins*).

I have both 2.7 and 3.0 installed (windows most of the time, occasionally working in my virtual machine with ubuntu). I will keep searching, but will greatly appreciate your input. This feels kind of basic but I'm learning and can't make it out myself at least for now.
Again, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`nltk.probability.FreqDist`](https://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.probability.FreqDist-class.html) is not [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects).

Use [`items`](https://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.probability.FreqDist-class.html#items) method to get a list of items in sorted order (most frequent first).

```
>>> from nltk.probability import FreqDist
>>> dist = FreqDist([1, 2, 1, 2, 1])
>>> dist.items()
[(1, 3), (2, 2)]
```

Or just use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter([1, 2, 1, 2, 1])
>>> c.most_common()
[(1, 3), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked for both this exercise and the previous one. 
I still wonder though why is it that they have most_common() as the name in the book  -changed it later so it doesn't create confusion with collections.Counter?.

Comment: Because the same functionality is implemented in `Counter.most_common`.
`c = Counter(some_list); c.most_common(:10)` == `fd = FreqDist(some_list); fd.most_common(:10)`

Answer (score 0):

Some old versions of nltk does not have `most_common` module. This can be verified by printing `dir(fdist)`.

If it is not found, simply upgrade the nltk version using pip as follows:

`sudo pip install -U nltk`

It should work.